# MPAndroidChart как задать шкалу X

Tags: android, диаграммы

День добрый товарищи,
использую библиотеку MPAndroidChart для отрисовки линейного графика изменения цены в зависимости от времени.
Со шкалой Y проблем не возникло, а вот шкалу X адекватно работать заставить не могу.
Есть вод который подставляет в эту шкалу нужное значение в зависимости от позиции:

```
IAxisValueFormatter formatter = new IAxisValueFormatter() {
    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        return quarters[(int) value];
    }
;
XAxis xAxis = mLineChart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setGranularity(1f); // minimum axis-step (interval) is 1
xAxis.setValueFormatter(formatter);
```

Но есть проблема, график отресовуеться по окончанию загрузки лоадером, а лоадет стартуеться выбором периода времени за который пользователь хочет видеть результат.
Если результат хотим видеть за 10 минут - то с сервера приходит меньше 10 значений, если за сутки, больше 100.
И проблема в том что почему то value не обновляеться, и когда после 100 значений мне нужно обратно посмотреть 10, он ищет в списке оси Y значения из 100, естественно не находит их так как у нас их всего 10 крашиться.
Собственно вопрос, как сбросить эти значения?
Перед передачей данных в график делаю mChart.clear();
Не понимаю в чём подвох. Помогите разобраться пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем решил так: написал свой форматер и в нём

```
@Override
public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
    if (value >= list.size()) {
        value = list.size() - 1;
    }
    Date date = new Date(list.get((int) value) * 1000);
    return formatter.format(date);
}
```